# Jasper Report Freeze header of Excel report

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using Jasper IReport designer version 3.7.6 . Is there any way to freeze the first two rows of the excel report that is generated? Below is a part of the column header. Row 1 is the PDD , Row 2 is Reparto. I want them freezed during scroll.

```
<columnHeader>
    <band height="24">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="12">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row.edge" value="Bottom"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ Pdd]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="50" height="12"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="7" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ Reparto]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

From the documentation : https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column

I tried to use:
**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row**

**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row.edge**

without success. I am guessing it's because I am using an older version of Jasper Ireport. Is there any alternative to achieve my goal **without** updating the version of the app. Updating the version is not an option.

Thank you

Comment: It appears that the feature to freeze rows in the XLS export of JasperReports is not available in version 3.7.6. The property "net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" and "net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row.edge" were added in later versions of JasperReports.

without upgrading to a newer version of JasperReports, it may not be possible to freeze rows in the generated XLS report using the current version of Jasper iReport Designer.

One alternative would be to export your report to a different format such as PDF, which allows for freezing rows in the exported document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the export type from xlsx to xls managed to solve the issue.